# Compact and countability axioms!

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I wondering which countability axioms compact imply in arbitrary topological spaces. I'm using [Greene/Gamelin](http://books.google.sk/books?id=thAHAGyV2MQC) 2nd ed.
And they list separable, 2nd-coutable, first-countable and Lindelöf.
Clearly compact implies Lindelöf but does it imply any of the others?

Comment: Maybe you mean compact *metric spaces*? (In Chapter 1 the book only deals with metric spaces.) If this is the case, you should mention it in the question and use the tag ([tag:metric-spaces]). I'm not sure, whether you should post a new question or edit this one. But if you edit this one, please, mark clearly what is the addition to your question. (Because there already exists an answer to the original question. Things like this were discussed on meta, for example [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/).)

Comment: [Prove: Every compact metric space is separable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190817/prove-every-compact-metric-space-is-separable)

Comment: I change it to any topological space, Im sorry for being unspecific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compact does not imply any of the others. Consider the [extended long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29), which is compact but not separable or first-countable (hence not second-countable). It is compact by definition (it is the two-point compactification of the long line). To see that it is not separable, note that for any countable collection of points $x_n$ we have some $\lambda\in \omega_1$ such that $x_n\notin\{\lambda\}\times (0,1)$ for all $n$ by the uncountability of $\omega_1$, and $\{\lambda\}\times (0,1)$ is open so the points $x_n$ are not dense. To see that it is not first-countable, let $U_n$ be a countable neighborhood basis for $+\infty$. Since each $U_n$ is open and contains $+\infty$, we have some $\lambda_n\in\omega_1$ such that $(\lambda_n,+\infty]\subseteq U_n$. But since $\omega_1$ is uncountable, we have some $\lambda\in \omega_1$ such that $\lambda>\lambda_n$ for all $n$, thus $U_n\not\subseteq (\lambda, +\infty]$, thus the $U_n$ are not a countable neighborhood basis for $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For an even simpler example let $D$ be any uncountable set, $p$ a point not in $D$, and $X=\{p\}\cup D$, and take

$$\mathscr{B}=\big\{\{x\}:x\in D\big\}\cup\{X\setminus F:F\subseteq D\text{ is finite}\}$$

as a base for the topology on $X$. ($X$ is the one-point compactification of $D$, where $D$ has the discrete topology.)

- $X$ is compact, because every open set containing $p$ has a finite complement in $X$.
- $X$ is not first countable, because $p$ does not have a countable local base. Let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable family of open nbhds of $p$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $F_n=X\setminus U_n$, and let $H=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$; each $F_n$ is finite, so $H$ is countable, and $D\setminus H\ne\varnothing$. Fix $x\in D\setminus H$, and let $V=X\setminus\{x\}$; then $V$ is an open nbhd of $p$, but $x\in U_n\setminus V$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $V$ contains no member of $\mathscr{U}$, and $\mathscr{U}$ therefore is not a local base at $p$.
- Every second countable space is trivially first countable, so $X$ is not second countable.