# A problem on countable dense subset on a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose for a metric space every infinite subset has a limit point. What should be my strategy to construct  a countable dense subset there? Additionally, how do I intuitively guess that with such a property the metric space has a countable dense subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit point. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $D_n$ be a maximal subset of $X$ such that $d(x,y)\ge 2^{-n}$ whenever $x,y\in D_n$ with $x\ne y$. (You can use Zorn’s lemma to show that $D_n$ exists.)

- Show that each $D_n$ is finite.
- Show that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}D_n$ is dense in $X$.

I’m not sure how you’d guess this result. The hypothesis on $X$ does tell you that $X$ does not contain an infinite closed discrete subset, which in some sense says that the points of $X$ aren’t spread out too much, but that property alone isn’t enough to ensure that $X$ is separable: the result really does use the fact that $X$ is a metric space as well.

Comment: M.Scott : I did not understand the meaning of maximal subset here. Why do we need to show the existence of $D_n$ using Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: @Prasenjit: Maximal with respect to $\subseteq$. In other words, if $D_n\subseteq S$, and $d(x,y)\ge 2^{-1}$ whenever $x,y\in S$ with $x\ne y$, then $S=D_n$. Another way to say this is that $\bigcup_{x\in D_n}B(x,2^{-n})=X$: every point of $X$ is already within $2^{-n}$ of some point of $D_n$. Zorn’s lemma is simply the easiest way to show that such a set exists.

Comment: M.Scott: Here each $D_n$ is finite. So, the process by which we choose stops after a finite number of steps. So, do we need Zorn's lemma/axiom of choice here ?

Comment: @Prasenjit: Yes: remember, we don't actually know that they're finite until we prove it. Of course we can use the axiom of choice in the form of a recursive construction instead. I suggested Zorn' s lemma because in my experience more students are familiar with it than with recursive constructions.

Comment: M.Scott : I did not understand how do you prove $D_n$ is finite from the existence of $D_n$ using Zorn's lemma. Suppose we have a set of points (which is $D_n$) such their neighbourhoods of radius $\delta$ will cover the metric space. This does not imply that the distance between any two points in $D_n$ is $\geq \delta$. But we need this two show that $D_n$ is finite. Am I correct ?

Comment: M.Scott: Another thing, does the existence of cover by a subset of a dense set is necessary to prove denseness ? i.e. Can there be a dense subset of a metric space for which there is no subset which covers the metric space ?

Comment: @Prasenjit: It’s two separate steps. First you prove that a set maximal with respect to the property that distinct points are $\ge 2^{-n}$ apart exists. Then you use the fact that it **is** maximal to show that it must be finite. // If $D$ is a dense subset of a metric space, then for each $\epsilon>0$ $\{B(x,\epsilon):x\in D\}$ covers the space. You won’t always be able to get a **finite** subset with this property; you can get it here because the condition that each infinite sets has a limit point actually implies that a metric space is compact.

Answer (score 0):

In metric spaces, every infinite subset having a limit point (limited point compactness) is equivalent to compactness.

Every compact metric space has a countable dense subset. See the answer to this question:

[Prove: Every compact metric space is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190817/prove-every-compact-metric-space-is-separable)

Comment: i am not sure this is correct. you can only have compactness if the limit point exists in the set.  see rudin pg 40 .. here in this case we do not know where the limit points are.  am i correct?