# Closure of range of a compact operator is separable

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, separation-axioms

Let $T \in K(\mathbb{H})$ , where $ K(\mathbb{H})$ is the space of all compact operators on Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$. I need to show that closure of ${Range (T)}$ is separable.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: More generally, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190817/prove-every-compact-metric-space-is-separable).

Comment: So this closure is compact?